# Use SourceGenerator with dependencies in same solution

Tags: c#, roslyn, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

Hi I'm trying to write a `SourceGenerator` that uses the `Humanizer` package (This package is only needed while generating code and should not be added as a reference in the project that uses the SourceGenerator)

So I have the following files:

TestSourceGenerator\TestSourceGenerator.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
        <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage);_AddAnalyzersToOutput</TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage>
        <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Humanizer.Core" Version="2.14.1" PrivateAssets="all" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="4.1.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.1.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="_AddAnalyzersToOutput">
        <ItemGroup>
            <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Pack="true" Visible="false" />
            <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="$(OutputPath)\Humanizer.dll" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Pack="true" Visible="false" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

TestSourceGenerator\SourceGenerator.cs

```cs
using System.Text;
using Humanizer;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

namespace TestSourceGenerator;

[Generator]
public class SourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {

        var builder = new StringBuilder(1024);

        builder.AppendLine(@$"using System;
namespace {context.Compilation.Assembly.ContainingNamespace?.Name ?? context.Compilation.Assembly.Name};
static class AssemblyInformation {{
    public static string Name = ""{context.Compilation.AssemblyName}"";
    public static string HumanizedName = ""{context.Compilation.AssemblyName.Humanize()}"";
}}
");

        context.AddSource("AssemblyInformation.cs", SourceText.From(builder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
    }

    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

TestSourceGenerator\Properties\launchSettings.json

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "Profile 1": {
      "commandName": "DebugRoslynComponent",
      "targetProject": "..\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1.csproj"
    }
  }
}
```

ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TestSourceGenerator\TestSourceGenerator.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="true"  />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

ConsoleApp1\Program.cs

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + AssemblyInformation.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + AssemblyInformation.HumanizedName);
```

Every thing works as expected when I debug the SourceGenerator using `Profile 1`.
But if I try to compile `ConsoleApp1` it complains that it can't find the `Humanizer` even when its there

```
Generator 'SourceGenerator' failed to generate source. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'FileNotFoundException' with message 'Could not load file or assembly 'Humanizer, Version=2.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=979442b78dfc278e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

What am I missing?
I have verified that Humanizer is part of the nuget file when I pack the SourceGenerator.

A copy of the code can be found here: https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/TestSourceGenerator

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#use-functionality-from-nuget-packages

Comment: @canton7 i have applied the changes according to that post, but it yields the same error, https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/TestSourceGenerator/tree/canton7

Comment: I don't know whether it matters, but the `PrivateAssets` attributes differ

Comment: Yeah, it works if you remove those. Make sure to restart VS -- it caches SGs very aggressively (you'll want to develop your SG using unit tests, which has the benefit of avoiding the problem)

Comment: @canton7 I'm somewhat confused where do my PrivateAssets differ? In my `TestSourceGenerator.csproj` I have Humanizer.Core with `PrivateAssets="all"` just like they have in the cookbook? But just for the fun I removed all PrivateAssets="all" cleaned my solution, restarted vs and ran again, same error :(

Comment: The cookbook does not have `PrivateAssets` at all, that's my point. I removed all 4 of those, cleaned, rebuilt, restarted VS, and it generated `static class AssemblyInformation` (you can see under ConsoleApp1 -> Dependencies -> Analyzers -> TestSourceGenerator in the solution explorer). Note that this class is generated in the `ConsoleApp1` namespace and your `Program.cs` isn't, so you need to tweak your console app to get it to actually build

Comment: @canton7 if you scroll to the second csproj under `Use functionality from NuGet packages` where they show you how to include Newtonsoft correctly in the nuget package, there they do have PrivateAssets and GeneratePathProperty? But I'm still confused why it works for you when you remove PrivateAssets and it dosen't for me. I even tried to build from cmd same issue `dotnet build ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj`.

Comment: If you open up the .nupkg manually, you've confirmed the files are there as you expect them to be?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski yes the nuget package looks correct, I also managed to get it to work when i add a `PackageReference` instead of a `ProjectReference`, so I guess `ProjectReference` just don't work that well with SourceGenerators.

Comment: @Peter If you reference the generator as ProjectReference, you need a different approach for handling dependencies, see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/main/samples/CSharp/SourceGenerators/SourceGeneratorSamples/CSharpSourceGeneratorSamples.csproj for example.

Comment: @Youssef13 Explaining what parts of that link are relevant would make a good answer.